# Who was the ruler of the Japanese Yomi?

Tags: japanese, underworld

The Japanese Underworld (Yomi) is said to be ruled by Izanami. However, in the tale of Ōkuninushi, Susanno is said to reside there as its king. In addition to that, Izanamzi told Inzangi that she had to ask for permission to get out of Yomi.

Who did she need to ask for permission? A ruler/god of Yomi? Who is the real ruler of Yomi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, Izanagi is the original ruler of Yomi, however, when Susanoo was banished there, he became ruler.

Texts on Yomi are very scarce, and finding out exactly how he became ruler, and what later became of Izanagi, remain scarce. I'll do some investigating soon for you.

Answer (score -3):

maybe she was going to ask Hades or the Chinese Yama, remember that the Japanese underworld shared various similitude with Greek underworld and various gods came from adaptations of china and India.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3440)

Comment: Welcome to Mythology.  As @bleh has mentioned, we tend to seek answers that have some support.  I don't disagree with the premise that you find cross-pollination in the myths of different cultures, and don't know much about the Japanese underworld, but you really need to support this answer with (ideally) academic links.  And you don't necessarily have to find a book or paper that supports the idea, but you should at least present details and citations to mythological source material to support your thesis.